# Reverse engineering algorithm for get keys

Tags: encryption

I have 2 groups of 4 byte and from this i have to get a key that have 6 byte.
Im trying to get the algorithm but i cant in any way.
The 1st group have only one bit different from the 2nd one.
Idk if i have to extract the 1st or the second key, but i think the 1st one.

1st group 4byte: `0x6339959F`
2nd group 4byte: `0x6339959E`

1st group keys:

```
0x38A39FE39EF5
0x296A852D73EA
```

2nd group keys:

```
0x39BF16EACF1A
0x28760C242205
```

i let a another group and relative keys:
group: `0x66CF0824`
keys:

```
0x92252BCADB80
0x83EC3104369F
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code which generates these numbers? It’s unlikely you’ll be able to recover the algorithm just from input/output pairs.

Comment: No, i cant access the code, only one person havbe the algoritm. He said is simple encryption

Comment: I think there should be more hints than “simple encryption”. What is the overall goal? Where’s the data coming from? Is this some challenge or homework?